# MySQL Workbench -- How to efficiently review large database tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a database table with 900,000+ rows, 20 columns, mostly string data.  Using MySQL Workbench, I want to page through the entire contents of the table to see what exactly has been inserted into the table (I am reviewing it because I believe my code somehow accidentally only partially loaded the contents of a CSV file and I want to understand why and where the process ceased loading the entire CSV file).

The problem is that, because of the somewhat large size of the DB table, running a "SELECT * FROM..." query with "Don't Limit" causes my computer to take far too long (over 10 minutes) to produce a result in MySQL Workbench's result grid and basically appears to freeze up.

Is there a way to make the MySQL Workbench result grid load much much faster?  Or should I be using a different tool?

I'm a bit of a noob, so it's possible I'm doing something pretty stupid here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `limit` and `offset` to just grab a subset of rows each time?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Yes, perhaps that is the best way to handle the data.  If I use `limit` and `offset` and only request specific columns instead of the entire table, the results grid loads significantly faster.  Of course, several queries with different offsets must be ran to view the entire table, but that is workable.

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can use something like "pager less" on the mysql client to page though the data. However, even at 10 pages/second, you'll be paging for 25 hours. Have fun! :-)

Comment: @Vérace I'm using Windows 8, although I think a similar "pager less" option exists in the command line utility.  That said, I agree with you that this would still be a very time consuming manner in which to review the data :).

Comment: Pager [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596412/mysql-5-5-25a-on-windows-is-missing-pager-command) on Windows. You could try sending it to a file and use your editor of choice to peruse the file - if you have a definite known end-point for your .csv load, that might be a better strategy than paging through results. Or!! You could save your table as a .csv (with a different name to your original file) and then do a [diff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830962/file-differencing-software-on-windows) on the files - that might immediately show up problems?

Comment: Check out [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html) - clearly states that "pager" won't work for Windows.

Comment: @Vérace Saving the table as a .CSV file (using MySQL's `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`) worked great.  I outputted a 118MB file that was much easier to explore in Excel.  As a side note, I figured out why the original .CSV file wasn't loading into the database correctly -- the original .CSV file contained a few rogue double quote characters that were causing the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement in my code to work incorrectly.

Comment: How about if I write this up as an answer, it may help others with the same problem - comments aren't searchable (and I may get a couple of points! :-) )

Comment: I agree that is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first suggestion was to use the "pager less" command - but as pointed out, even at 10 pages a second, it would take 25 hours to get through 900,000 records.

Unfortunately, the "pager" command doesn't work on Windows. It was then suggested to send the output to a file and scroll through that - looking for a disconnect between the .csv input and the final table.

Then, this was proposed

```
    Or!! You could save your table as a .csv (with a different name  
to your original file) and then do a diff on the files - that might 
immediately show up problems?
```

This appears to have resolved the issue for the OP.